# Cardinal directions in Ruby array

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to create a program that will keep track of a person's bearing as they turn left and right (e.g., if they are facing north and turn left, they will face north.) I wrote the as an array that works in both ways. Here's my code so far:

```
puts "What is your initial bearing?"
bearing = gets.chomp

puts "And what turns do you want to make?"
turn_list = gets.chomp

cardinal_directions = ["N", "E", "S", "W"]

position = cardinal_directions.index(bearing)
turn_list.each |direction|
case "L"
    position += 1
case "R" 
    position -= 1
end
```

But there's an obvious problem. Say my person is facing west and wants to turn right. How can I tell it it to go from index 3 to index 0? Or if they are at north and want to turn left?

Please excuse crappy code and formatting, I am a novice. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Quick note: that's not the syntax for case statements. Just use an if, or here's the syntax for case: http://www.skorks.com/2009/08/how-a-ruby-case-statement-works-and-what-you-can-do-with-it/

Comment: "if they are facing north and turn left, they will face north." Is that really what you mean?

Comment: @steenslag, that could be true, depending on where you are standing.

Comment: @CarySwoveland  southpole ?

Comment: Somebody give that man (@steenslag) a cigar.

Comment: @Linuxios you're right, and thank you for the link.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have 4 possible options, you can use modular arithmetic (i.e., get the remainder) when your variable is divided by 4:

```
case turn_list
when "R"
    position = (position + 1)%4
when "L" 
    position = (position - 1)%4
end
```

The `%` sign is the modulo operator that will give you the remainder when two numbers are divided. That should give you the answer you want. For example, if you are at position 3 (West) and turn right you add 1 and divide by 4 and get take the remainder, which is 0 (North).

(I edited cases "R" and "L" because I think you had them labeled backwards in your question.)

Comment: Just a note for anyone who doesn't know: `%` is the remainder, or modular arithmetic operator. Ex. 3 % 2 = 1, or 4 % 5 = 4.

Comment: Thanks, @Linuxios. I'll make it a little more clear in my answer. Thanks also for noting the incorrect `case` syntax in the original question.

Comment: No problem. Just thought it might help the OP if they weren't familiar with modular arithmetic in Ruby.

Comment: @Linuxios: In Ruby `%` is the modulus or modulo operator and not the remainder operator. In this case (non-negative values) it doesn't make a difference though.

Comment: @cremno: Yes, formally. It can be thought of (under certain circumstances) as a remainder operator.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array#rotate!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-rotate-21) passing 1(or nothing, as 1 is the default argument) to go right and -1 to go left, always keeping the original position:

```
cardinal_directions = ["N", "E", "S", "W"]
# => ["N", "E", "S", "W"] 
position = cardinal_directions.index('S')
# => 2 
cardinal_directions.rotate!(1)
# => ["E", "S", "W", "N"] 
cardinal_directions[position]
# => "W" 
cardinal_directions.rotate!(1)
# => ["S", "W", "N", "E"] 
cardinal_directions[position]
# => "N" 
cardinal_directions.rotate!(1)
# => ["W", "N", "E", "S"] 
cardinal_directions[position]
# => "E" 
cardinal_directions.rotate!(-1)
# => ["S", "W", "N", "E"] 
cardinal_directions[position]
# => "N" 
cardinal_directions.rotate!(-1)
# => ["E", "S", "W", "N"] 
cardinal_directions[position]
# => "W"
```

Comment: This is a great, very Rubyish solution.

Comment: The OP asked that an index between `0` and `3` be returned. That's of course an easy change, of course, and possibly not one that is advised, depending on the OP's application.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I am just showing another way. The other answer already covers how OP can use modulo to get the index.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you employ a class to keep track of each person's bearing:

```
class Wanderers
  attr_accessor :name, :bearing

  def initialize(name, initial_bearing, at_south_pole = false)
    @name = name
    @bearing = at_south_pole ? :north : initial_bearing
    @at_south_pole = at_south_pole
  end

  def turn_left
    return :north if @at_south_pole
    @bearing = 
    case @bearing
    when :north  then :west
    when :west   then :south
    when :south  then :east
    when :east   then :north
    end
  end

  def turn_right
    return :north if @at_south_pole
    @bearing = 
    case @bearing
    when :north  then :east
    when :east   then :south
    when :south  then :west
    when :west   then :north
    end
  end
end
```

Then:

```
hector = Wanderers.new "Hector", :east
hector.turn_right #=> :south 
hector.turn_right #=> :west 
hector.turn_right #=> :north 
hector.turn_right #=> :east 
hector.turn_left  #=> :north 
hector.bearing    #=> :north 

lola = Wanderers.new "Lola", :north, true
lola.turn_right   #=> :north 
lola.turn_right   #=> :north 
lola.turn_left    #=> :north 
lola.bearing      #=> :north
```

Comment: I see I forgot the North Pole case. Oh, well.